# Finding the zero-state response

Tags: circuit-analysis

I understand the zero state response can be found by finding the homogeneous and particular solution. I am analyzing this circuit.

[image]

My input is $$Vin(t) = e^(-2t) * u(t)$$
I set the Vout to 0. So for the homogeneous equation I have $$0 = \frac{-4}{i} * \frac{dv(t)}{dt} + v(t), t< 0$$
And for the particular solution I have $$1 = \frac{-4}{i} * \frac{dv(t)}{dt} + v(t), t > 0$$ However, given all this, how do I proceed? Also, is there a simpler way of doing this for more complicated circuits? For instance, if the resistor and capacitor positions were switched or if I had a really complicated transfer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\$i=C\dfrac{dv_o}{dt}\$, and Ohm's Law gives: \$v_i - v_o=RC\dfrac{dv_o}{dt}\$

This can be solved by the integrating factor method, and zero state means zero initial conditions, therefore take \$v_o(0)=0\$

For higher order (>2) circuits you'll need the Laplace Transform.

Comment: So I actually got upto there, which is in my question. But couldn't finish it; thus I replaced vi with the unit function for the homo and particular equation. Can you please carry out the problem further?

Comment: Have you covered the integrating factor method? Write the DE as: \$\frac{dv_o}{dt}+\frac{1}{RC}v_o=\frac{1}{RC}v_i\$, then it's a pretty standard solution with \$v_i=e^{-2t}u(t)\$

Comment: ... if you wish, you can write the input as \$v_i=e^{-2t}\$, noting that \$v_i=0\$ for t<0; the unit step function just forces this condition.